# Calling function pointed by void* pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I have an event struct that looks like this

```
typedef struct {
    void* fn;
    void* param;
} event;
```

How can I call this function by pointer as part of the struct.  For example, these do not work:

```
event->(*function)();
event->function();
(*event->function)();
```

I want to know how to make the function call both with and without using the additional void* param.  I was originally using this link as a reference:

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html

I've used these function pointers before, but have trouble getting the syntax correct.

Comment: You need to cast `void*` into a function pointer first. Or do you want to declare pointer to the function that returns nothing?

Comment: How do you cast into a function pointer correctly with you are dereferencing a struct pointer like in this case?

Comment: You have `fn` in the type declaration, but refer to `function` in the calls. Are they supposed to be the same thing? If you want `fn` to hold a function pointer, it needs to be declared as a function pointer, not as a `void*` (you can likely get away with converting a `void*` to a function pointer, but it's not guaranteed to work). Furthermore, `event` is a type, not an object or expression; you need to have an object of type `event` before you can refer to its `fn` member.

Comment: [That tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html) doesn't try to store a function pointer in a `void*`. Why are you trying to do so?

Comment: I edited the OP so that it's consistent.  Basically, I need to store the function pointers in a struct like this and call the functions by pointer.  I am not sure of the best way to do that and the tutorial isn't clearing it up for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to cast `void*` pointer to the function pointer first:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    void* fn;
    void* param;
} event;

void print()
{
        printf("Hello\n");
}


int main()
{
    event e;
        e.fn = print;
        ((void(*)())e.fn)();
        return 0;
}
```

Of course, if this is really what you want. If you want your struct to contain pointer to the function, instead of `void*` pointer, use the proper type at the declaration:

```
typedef struct {
    void (*fn)();
    void* param;
} event;
```

Here you have `fn` declared as a pointer to the `void` function, and the `param` as `void*` pointer.

Comment: Thank you!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I apologize for all of the errors when asking the question.

Comment: Note that this is technically not legal. Pointers to objects and pointers to functions are not convertible (6.2.3.3(8)). You must use the second form, where the member is a function pointer from the start.

Comment: This causes UB. You can not store a function pointer in a `void *` pointer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you're probably looking for this:

```
typedef struct {
    void (*fn)();
    void (*param)();
} event;


event *E;

E->fn();
E->param();
```

Answer (score 1):

`event` is a *type*, not an object or expression. You can't access a member of a structure type, only of an object of a structure type.

So given:

```
typedef struct {
    void* fn;
    void* param;
} event;
```

you need to have an object of type `event`, and you need to assign values to its members.

In your question, you use `fn` as a member name, but then you refer to something called `function`. I'll assume here that they're supposed to be the same thing, and that `fn` is supposed to point to some function.

You can't portably store a function pointer in a `void*`. On many, probably most, implementations you can get away with it, but it's not guaranteed by the language. (There are systems were function pointers are bigger than data pointers, and converting a function pointer to `void*` loses information.) On the other hand, all pointer-to-function types are convertible to each other, and a round-trip conversion is guaranteed to give you the original pointer value.

I'll assume (I'm making a lot of assumptions here because you didn't provide a lot of information) that you want `fn` to point to a function that takes a `void*` argument and doesn't return a result; then making `param` a `void*` makes sense. For consistency with that assumption, we can alter your type definition:

```
typedef struct {
    void (*fn)(void*);
    void *param;
} event;
```

(The `void (*fn)(void*);` syntax is not entirely obvious. I used [`cdecl`](http://cdecl.org/) to construct it.)

Now you can define an object of type `event`:

```
event e = { some_func, NULL };
```

You have to have defined `some_func` somewhere, as

```
void some_func(void *param { /* ... */ }
```

or equivalent.  Now you can call that function indirectly through the `event` object `e`:

```
e.fn(e.param);
```

Or, if it's more convenient to have a *pointer* to an `event`:

```
event *ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr);
if (event == NULL) {
    /* error handling here */
}
ptr->fn = some_func;
ptr->param = NULL;
```

and you can use indirection both on the pointer-to-`event` and on the function pointer contained in the `event` object it points to:

```
ptr->fn(ptr->param);
```

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you might want `fn` to be able to point to functions of different types. If you do that, you *must* convert (with an explicit cast) `e.fn` or `ptr->fn` to the actual type of the function it points to before making a call through it. You can't blindly mix function pointers of different types; if you do, the result is either a compile-time error or run-time undefined behavior. You can use `void (*)(void)` (pointer to function with no parameters and returning no result) as a "generic" function pointer type, but unlike with `void*` any conversions to the type you need must be explicit.)

> I want to know how to make the function call both with and without using the additional `void*` param.

To call a function with no argument, simply use `()` in the function call. But again, for a given function, you can't choose to call it with or without a parameter; the call has to match the definition. (Except perhaps for variadic functions like `printf`, but you still need a function pointer of the correct type, and a variadic function can't be called with no arguments.)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible in a valid C program that does not cause undefined behavior (UB). `void *` can point to a valid objects, one byte after the last object of an array or to `NULL`, but functions are not objects.
What you can do is converting between different pointer to function.
But please keep in mind that you have to cast the function pointer back to the right type before you call the function pointer. Calling a function pointer that points to a function with a different type causes UB.

Many embedded platforms have separate storage for functions and the functions are not loaded into RAM, there a pointer to `void *` is  often smaller than a pointer to function.
On Posix compatible platforms you can convert pointers to function to `void *` and back, without causing UB. But that is a Posix extension and required for functions like `dlsym()`, it is not part of C.